# FreeType upgrade from 2.2.1 to 2.4.9 not seen by php 5.2.17

Tags: php, upgrade, redhat, freetype

I'm trying to upgrade a freetype installation from 2.2.1 to 2.4.9. I've done this on three other servers and those upgraded without a hitch, but one one, php just doe not see the new freetype. Here are the steps I've used:

Install Freetype:
./configure
make && make install

Recompile php-5.2.17:
    ./configure  --prefix=/usr/local \
    --sysconfdir=/etc \
    --localstatedir=/var \
    --with-openssl=/usr \
    --with-curl=/usr/local/lib \
    --enable-sockets \
    --enable-track-vars \
    --with-oci8=/opt/oracle/product/11.1.0.6/ \
    --with-zlib=yes \
    --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs \
    --enable-sigchild \
    --with-java=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_21 \
    --with-gd \
    --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/freetype2 \
    --enable-gd-native-ttf \
    --with-ldap

After this, freetype-config --ftversion reports 2.4.9, but php -i displays 2.2.1. I suspect the problem lies with the freetype directory, but that seems correct. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. The default prefix path used by freetype is what should be used for the --with-freetype-dir. By default, freetype uses --prefix=/usr/local, so rebuilding php with that path solved my issue and php -i displays the correct freetype version of 2.4.9.